# Ruby on Rails: How to Get the Client IP Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip-address

I have searched a lot, and I could not find a solution. I tried:

```
Rails.logger.error request.remote_ip
Rails.logger.error request.env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

But the result is something weird: `10.130.150.254` or `10.130.150.251`.

I used my cell phone's LTE/4G networking to test, and it always gave me `10.130.247.251`, which is a Class A reserved private network IP address.

I also tried:

```
Rails.logger.error request.env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
Rails.logger.error request.env["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]
Rails.logger.error request.env["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]
```

But those gave me empty strings.

When I use my cell phone and point to touch.whatsmyip.org, it gives me: `172.56.9.89`, which is a public IP address.

We use HTTPS SSL termination and a load balancer, it probably looks like "[Get Remote Host Client IP Behind Load Balancers (ELB)](http://blog.svnlabs.com/get-remote-host-client-ip-behind-load-balancers-elb)".

How do I get the client IP address? If the client is behind a proxy, that's fine, then the proxy IP address is also good for me.

I'm using Apache and Passenger to serve the application.

"[request.remote_ip](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/heroku/jNLLpV-a6xk)" is a similar issue.

Comment: Have you compared the results of `request.remote_ip` to `request.ip`?

Comment: The "Related" links on the right side of the page are your friend. The techniques, and problems, are the same for PHP, Net and Ruby. Proxies, NATs, etc., can obscure/hide what IP the user is really on. People can bounce off other boxes or use [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/)-like systems, so getting something accurate can be difficult.

Comment: @theTinMan, I did searched a lot of stackoverflow posts before I posted mine :-) See my own answer.

Comment: As a suggestion when you're writing text containing links, use something more indicative when writing the link-text. Saying "this" is of no real help to anyone reading the text because "this" tells them nothing about what the link goes to. See the W3's pages "[Don't use 'click here' as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" and the section "[6.1 Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)" in "HTML Techniques for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0" for more information.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that our IT had not configured to pass it at the Load Balancer.  Once he finished configuring, it works.  Both `request.env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` and `request.remote_ip` works.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, if you weren't you should be by now, but just to iterate again: Using this for any kind of public service isn't reliable so don't make any kind of logic depend upon this unless you know the visitors to the server are most likely not spoofing (i.e. interoffice services).

Comment: can you share your server configuration changes

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will be helpful

`env['action_dispatch.remote_ip'].calculate_ip`